# Dependencies Between Workflows on Github Actions not working

Tags: github, github-actions

I have two workflows and i do from this manual - https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onworkflow_runbranchesbranches-ignore  but dependent workflow not starting..

```
name: Tests

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - '**'        # matches every branch
      - '!main'   # excludes master
  
jobs:
  setup-tests-job:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

and dependent workflow

```
name: Build

on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: 
      - 'Tests'
    branches: 
      - '**'
    types: 
      - completed
  
jobs:
   setup-tests-job:
     runs-on: ubuntu-latest
```

Maybe i do smthg wrong?